# is this feature available while creating sharepoint workflow for a list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a sharepoint list that has a number column call xyz
i am creating a sharepoint designer workflow for that list
in which i want to use update this list item action

if we chose actions as update this list item
then chose the list as current item
then chose set this field -> xyz 
to this value -> { how can i select here current value of xyz - 1 } i.e a variable formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two steps. First, declare a workflow variable (I'll call it "sample" here).
Then, add a workflow step "do calculation" and set `sample` to `xyz-1`. The text line Designer shows you will look like `Calculate <workflow name>:xyz minus 1 (Output to variable: sample` afterwards.

Then, set the xyz value to current value of `sample`.